# remote caching autocomplete issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have an autocomplete which uses a remote datasource. I tried to cache it, like in http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache.

Unfortunately, something isn't working, but doesn't show any errors in the Chrome Developer Panel.

Here's the code:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var cache = {};
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    var term = request.term;
                    if ( term in cache ) {
                        response( cache[ term ] );
                        return;
                    }
                $.getJSON( "suggest.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                    cache[ term ] = data;
                    response( data );
                    });
            });
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                        item.label = item.label.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
                        return $("<li></li>")
                                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                                .appendTo(ul);
                    };
        });
    </script>
```

and the html:

```
    <form method='get' action='search.php'>
     <input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search' id="search" autocomplete="off"/>
     <input type='submit' value=''>
    </form>
```

and the php:

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gjpages', 'root', 'mysql96');
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  if (!isset($_GET['term'])) {
     header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
     echo 'Missing term parameter in request';
     exit();
  }

 $queryString = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE :qs" . " UNION SELECT cat AS name FROM cat WHERE cat LIKE :qs" . " UNION SELECT subcat AS name FROM subcat WHERE subcat LIKE :qs " . " LIMIT 4");
 $query->execute(array(':qs' => $queryString . '%'));
 $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
 $result = array_map(function($row) {
    return array('label'=>$row['name'],'value'=>$row['name']);
 }, $query->fetchAll());

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo(json_encode($result));
?>
```

The php is working fine, it's the javascript that has the issue (I believe). What's the problem?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: have you tried putting breakpoints in your javascript and testing?

Comment: Is the autocomplete not working at all or is just the caching not working? If it is not working at all, it might be that request in $.getJSON() needs to be {term: request.term}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SandorA comment worked.

I needed to change it to be {term: request.term} to get it working again.